# URL rewrite rule is not working

Tags: url, url-rewriting

My url is http://example.com/index.php?pid=software_details&p=18 I want to change my url to http://example.com/software_details/18. I used .htaccess file to do this but it's not working... please someone help me! thanks in advance...!

My .htaccess code is as bellow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /index.php?pid=$1&p=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the rule below should achieve what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?pid=$1&p=$2 [R=301,L]
```